# How to modify Drupal 7 events calendar week view to include Sunday?

Tags: calendar, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal 7, and I have a problem where the events calendar week view doesn't show Sunday events, because the end date in the query is incorrect. Actually it only ever shows 6 days. How can I modify the query? How can I even find where it is generated?

Below is the query from the Events Calendar (Content) page. You can see that the start date comparison is ">= '2016-11-14 00:00:00" end date comparison is "<= '2016-11-20 00:00:00'", which doesn't retrieve events happening on Sunday. I need to change it to "<= '2016-11-20 23:59:59'".

Changing the first day of the week doesn't help, because it just shifts the six day time frame to start on Sunday, and misses events on both Saturday and Sunday.

SELECT field_data_field_event_date.delta AS field_data_field_event_date_delta, field_data_field_event_date.entity_id AS date_id_field_event_date, field_data_field_event_date.delta AS date_delta_field_event_date, node.nid AS nid, field_data_field_event_date.language AS field_data_field_event_date_language, field_data_field_event_date.bundle AS field_data_field_event_date_bundle, field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value AS field_data_field_event_date_field_event_date_value, field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value2 AS field_data_field_event_date_field_event_date_value2, field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_rrule AS field_data_field_event_date_field_event_date_rrule, node.title AS node_title, 'node' AS field_data_field_event_date_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_event_cat_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_event_date} field_data_field_event_date ON node.nid = field_data_field_event_date.entity_id AND field_data_field_event_date.entity_type = 'node'
WHERE (( (DATE_FORMAT(field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= '2016-11-14 00:00:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') <= '2016-11-20 00:00:00') )AND(( (node.status = '1') )))
ORDER BY field_data_field_event_date_field_event_date_value ASC

Answer (score 1):

I would first check your regional settings asyou can change the First day of the week there and just resave the value there - possibly try ye olde on-and-off again, switch between monday and sunday. /admin/config/regional/settings

Secondly, have you checked the module itself for this issue? A patch may be posted under their issue queue.

If all else fails, you could use [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x) in a custom module to modify the where clause of the query that is generated. I've written a blog post on this hook previously found [here](https://dev.acquia.com/blog/last-ditch-fix-programmatically-changing-drupal-7-view) but basically you have all the components of the query so can alter what you need there. Eg.

```
 // add the condition of greater than current timestamp
 $date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
   'field' => 'field_mytimefield_value',
   'value' => $date,
   'operator' => '>='
 );
```

Comment: I found where the problem happens in modules/contrib/date/date_views/includes/date_views_argument_handler_simple.inc, line 323. I changed that to:     $max_date = new DateTime($this->date_handler->granularity == 'week' ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->max_date . ' +1 day')) : $this->max_date);
    $view_max = date_format($max_date, $format);

Comment: One thing I would comment on is that it's generally not a good idea to just update contrib modules as the next time you go to update the module this will get over-written and break again. I'd recommend making this change also into a patch file so that you can re-apply the patch on update and possibly posting your fix on the module itself in the issue queue (if it's not already posted). Or you could move the module into the custom folder as you have now made custom changes.